# Cómo arreglar strings con carácteres especiales mal codificados Python

Tags: python, string

esto me ha pasado varias veces al trabajar con datos en español. Importo una base de datos con datos string, pero los tildes y eñes vienen mal codificados. En este caso tengo strings como los siguientes:

```
Estimado Cliente, la empresa le informa que su reclamo est\xa0 en proceso de |gesti¢n por parte de nuestra \xa0rea de atenci¢n

nuestros ejecutivos se pondr\xa0 en contacto v¡a |correo electr¢nico
```

Es claro que `\xa0 = á` , `¢ = ó`, `¡ = í` , etc. Siempre he pensado que debiera existir alguna forma automática de parsear estos strings para que queden bien presentados. Pero si el error viene de la fuente original, tal vez no se puede. Saben si es posible hacer algo, más allá de crear un diccionario y reemplazar carácter por carácter?

Saludos y gracias

Edit: agrego el `print(repr(datos))`:

```
 'Estimado Cliente, la empresa le informa que su reclamo est\xa0 en proceso de |gesti¢n por parte de nuestra \xa0rea de atenci¢n clientes. durante los |pr¢ximos d¡as uno de nuestros ejecutivos se pondr\xa0 en contacto v¡a |correo electr¢nico y/o telef¢nico para indicar los pasos a seguir o |bien la soluci¢n de su caso. |Equipo de Servicio al Cliente'
```

Comment: ¿Qué codificación estás utilizando?

Comment: `latin-1` y `utf-8` entregan el mismo resultado (He probado ambas, además de `ISO-8859-1`)

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la cadena en crudo de bytes que recibes, `print(repr(datos))` donde `datos` sea lo que recibes de la bd directamente?

Comment: @FJSevilla lo agregué al Edit, gracias